# Discern false modesty from the genuine (one)?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

In this sentence

> As she was not good at ***discerning false modesty from the genuine (one)***, people would easily take advantage of her credulousness.

In order to sound correct and natural, is *one* necessary? Or should I just repeat *modesty*?

Edit: Is it possible to say it in a different order:

> As she was not good at ***discerning genuine modesty from false***, people would easily take advantage of her credulousness.

Comment: Modesty is uncountable, so I would suggest _false modesty from genuine_.

Comment: Omit 'the' and 'one'.

Comment: Both comments above are relevant and useful.

Comment: I wish I could reward them. But I see that it is a common practice to comment rather than to answer. So I will just say thank you.

Comment: @fev - you can upvote comments.

Comment: I know and I have. But that doesn't give reps to the ones who commented, does it

Comment: @KateBunting ‘This might be the reason for my hesitation: embarrassment, brought on by a becoming modesty.’ [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/becoming) example sentence for 'becoming' (1.1 suitable or appropriate).

Comment: @fev - it's still nice to see.

Comment: @fev - on this site, answers, even 'good' ones, to lower quality questions can get downvotes, so sometimes people prefer comments as they are safer for your reputation. Some people might think your question is borderline off-topic for this site.

Comment: Is there a site where I can ask questions like this one?

Comment: @fev There is [ell.se].

Comment: In informal concersational U.S. English, you might express this idea as "discerning [or _distinguishing_ or _telling_] false modesty from the real thing [or _real deal_]."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that people have answered in the comments (naughty!). I'll answer the way I was going to anyway.

**Answer**

She was not good at discerning false modesty from  genuine.  (*genuine* is an adjective so does not take an article)

or

She was not good at discerning false modesty from the genuine sort. (*sort* is a noun and so takes an article)

Comment: Can I reverse false and genuine? (See Edit in my question)

Comment: You can say it but I wouldn't personally. It seems preferable to emphasis the sort of modesty you *do* want before the sort you don't.

Comment: "She was not good at discerning false from genuine modesty" - would that work?

Comment: @fev It looks like it should, but it doesn’t. I suspect this is because “false modesty” has become something like a compound word, whereas “genuine modesty” is still very much a 2-word phrase. Kind of like distinguishing between ice cream and whipped cream. You could just about get away with “ice cream and whipped”, but not with “ice and whipped cream”.